# I need to decrease the length of underlining of my Menu(Ant Design)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHt5t.png)
and i need this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6DBg.png)
do you guys can help me??

I tried other forums about underlined but nothing helps me
that is what i did to make this menu like this already:

```
.ant-menu-item-selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(32, 143, 137, 1) !important;
    color: rgba(32, 143, 137, 1) !important;
    height: 32px;
    
  }
```

```
<ConfigProvider
                        theme={{
                            components: {
                            Menu: {
                                fontSize:14,
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                                colorPrimary: 'trasnparent',
                                itemPaddingInline:18,
                                colorBgTextHover:'#208F89',
                                itemHoverColor:'rgba(32, 143, 137, 1)',
                                horizontalLineHeight:'38px',
                                horizontalItemHoverBg:'rgba(237, 241, 246, 1)',
                                colorSplit:'transparent',
                                                             
                            },                         
                        }
                        }}
                    >
 <Menu style={{}} onClick={onClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items}></Menu>
 </ConfigProvider>
```